# upload file after login using curl shell script

Tags: linux, shell, curl

I'm trying to upload file from linux to a webserver after login (using CURL).
I've written the below code for uploading the file. (its working fine). But, I could not find a way to login and to keep track the login session when uploading the file.

```
curl -F "Filedata=@/home/ubuntu/myfile.mp4" -F "myotherqueryvar=queryvalue" -L http://website.com/file_uploader.php > html_out.txt
```

can anyone help me for this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the cookie that is set when you login.

```
-c cookie.txt
```

create the `cookie` file and chmod it to so it can be written.

1 - Login and save the cookie (`-c cookie`)
2 - Post your file with the cookie you've saved before.

```
curl -c cookie -F "Filedata=@/home/ubuntu/myfile.mp4" -F "myotherqueryvar=queryvalue" -L http://website.com/file_uploader.php > html_out.txt
```